# javascript dates converted to bst time on android devices when using Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I have a web application that runs on Chrome without any problems on a Android Device but when running it on Firefox it converts the "newvalue" to BST time zone instead of GMT Standard Time.

```
var  now = new Date();
var start = new Date();
var newvalue = new Date(now - start);
```

The newvalue timezone output is GMT+0100(BST) but should actually be GMT+0000(GMT Standard Time)

Firefox is adding an an extra hour.

I have tried to convert to UTC and GMT but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK so ... Ermmm ... I'm not clear on what you're doing with the line:

```
var newvalue = new Date(now - start);
```

Are you trying to time something?

Regardless, the first thing this line does is to subtract start from now, and give the difference between the 2 dates in milliseconds.  Assuming this happens basically instantly, the result will be approximately (if not precisely) 0 milliseconds.

When you create a date and pass in a single parameter like this, you are asking for the date as it was, X milliseconds after epoch.  Epoch is defined as Thursday Jan 1st 1970 (for reasons I won't go into).  So by creating a new Date with a parameter of 0, you're just asking the browser to give you epoch.

Why Firefox decides to **give** you epoch in BST instead of GMT, I'll grant is actually pretty odd (since Jan 1st is clearly *not* in British Summer Time).  But this fact is probably irrelevant, given that this is almost certainly NOT what you are trying to achieve here.  If you're trying to time something, I'd suggest you probably just want to do:

```
var newvalue = start - now;
```

Where newvalue is now the difference in time.  Note: I have swapped now and start around, since in your example start is defined after now, and hence this will give you the positive time difference.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

To be clear, I'm suggesting that you DON'T create a new Date object with the result of the subtraction.

If you want to get the number of milliseconds between the two times using dates, just subtract them:

```
var start = new Date();
// do time consuming stuff
var end = new Date();
var difference = end - start; // NOT: var difference = new Date(end - start)
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I am a running a timer if I do as you have advised then it resets the time to 23:59:00. The BST is the think that is very odd..?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by turning the two dates in to a UTC date and then finding the difference between the two dates using milliseconds.
This then works on Android.

Thanks for your assistance